# How to erase the content on a graphics in GDI+?

Tags: canvas, gdi+

I am using gdi+, in c++.

```
Bitmap canvasImg = new Bitmap(400, 300, PixelFormat32bppARGB);
Graphics canvas = new Graphics(&canvasImg );

canvas.DrawImage(XXXX);
```

There are two problems.

1. I find the canvasImg is black. How can I change the color to white? I mean I want an white canvas.

2. If I have drawn some thing on the canvas, How can I clear the canvas?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to both questions is to use `canvas.Clear(Color.White)` or whatever your desired canvas color is.